# Import graphical views of a scadabr project

Tags: automation, scada

I want to export the graphical views of my Scadabr project to use them on an other computer, I selected all cases of my project parts that I want to export (also the case of the graphical views) and when I import the project on the other computer, there is no graphical views!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that, when you import a project the components of the graphicals views are uploaded and you  just have the upload the images of the background.